# Is the family of circles $x^2+y^2-((a^2+b^2+1+2fb)/a)x+2fy+1=0$ coaxial for constants $a$, $b$ and parameter $f$?

Tags: geometry, circles, parametric, parametrization

> The equation of a family of circles is -
>
> $$x^2+y^2-((a^2+b^2+1+2fb)/a)x+2fy+1=0$$ where $a$, $b$ are real constants and $f$ is a real parameter.
>
> How can I check whether this family of circles is coaxial or not?

I want to know how to approach the problem (i.e. what is the condition for being coaxial)

Comment: Do you know how to find the radical axis of $C_1\colon x^2+y^2+a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $C_2\colon x^2+y^2+a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$?

Comment: This is a two dimensional problem, so do you mean "concentric" when you say "coaxial"?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor coaxial here refers to circles having the same radical axis

Comment: But I neither know how to find radical axis nor check if they are same for all circles?

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo in the equation.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor But how were you able to deduce that circles will have the same radius in the original equation?

Comment: Ugh, my apologies, the circles are not all the same radius.  Deleting my erroneous comments.

Comment: Will it help if the question was in complex equation form?

Comment: Should I ask the original question which was in complex form?

Comment: @InfiniteCool23: A convenient thing about circle equations is that if you combine two of them in such a way that the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms cancel, then what remains is the equation of the radical axis. So, consider two versions of your equation: one with parameter $f$ and one with parameter, say, $g\neq f$. Check whether the equation of the radical axis depends upon $f$ or $g$.

Comment: @Blue that is a crucial clue, thank you!

Comment: So my approach of starting by completing the square was completely wrong.

Comment: @Blue Ok thanks, I will try to do it this way.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: *"So my approach of starting by completing the square was completely wrong."* Not *wrong*, but perhaps more work than necessary in this case.

Comment: @Blue So, I took two parameters f1 and f2 and subtracted the two equations (to eliminate x^2 and y^2 terms. I finally got b(f2-f1)x=a(f2-f1)y. Then as f1 not equal to f2 they will cancel.

Comment: Hence we get bx=ay which is independent of any parameter. So can I say that the circles are coaxial? And bx=ay will be equation of radical axis, right?

Comment: @InfiniteCool23: Bingo! :) ... Post your work as an answer so that we can upvote your success (and to remove the question from the unanswered queue).

Comment: @Blue Actually, I think you should post the clue that you gave as the answer, then I will upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: Couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: @InfiniteCool23: Glad to be of service. For homework (or whenever), go figure out why the subtract-the-equations trick works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer, as requested.

---

A convenient thing about circle equations is that, if you combine two of them in such a way that the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms cancel, then what remains is the equation of the radical axis.

So, consider two versions of your equation: one with parameter $f$ and one with parameter, say, $g\neq f$. Check whether the equation of the radical axis depends upon $f$ or $g$.

---

Since OP has correctly solved the problem in the comments to the question, I'll include a little bit more.

In this case, it can be helpful to clear fractions and move the "parameterized" terms to one side. This gives
$$a x^2 + a y^2 - ( a^2 + b^2 + 1 ) x + a = 2 f ( b x - a y )$$
From here, it's pretty clear that the difference of two distinct instances will be a multiple of $0 = bx-ay$, which is therefore the equation of the common radical axis.